# What are typically the headers which I should oversign?

Tags: email, email-server, dkim, opendkim, e-mailrelay

I am trying to setup MTA using Postfix and using opendkim for dkim signing. When I went through opemdkim documentation it have a field which is named 'OversignHeaders' document describes it as: "Specifies a set of header fields that should be included in all signature header lists (the "h=" tag) once more than the number of times they were actually present in the signed message.". I have doubts regarding what should (if anything) be included in the dataset.

Please correct me; from what I understood what this option does is to dynamically (as if meant by the number of instances of the headers) allow signing header even if there are more than one instance of the header and adding an additional empty instance (just like to mean the end of this type of headers).  What I am unable to correlate is the practical need of this dynamic signing (as what headers could have been repeated earlier can also get repeated later thus breaking the validity). It'll be helpful if someone can explain by say an example.

Comment: The OversignHeaders option in OpenDKIM allows you to specify additional headers that should be signed, even if they're not present in the message being signed. This can be useful if you want to include headers beyond the default set. So do you want to sign additional headers?

Comment: Please correct me; from what I understood this can also be done by the Signheaders option what this option do is to dynamically (as if meant by the number of instances of the headers) allow signing header even if there are more than one instances of the header and adding additional empty instance (just like to mean the end of this type of headers).  What I am unable to correlate is the practical need of this dynamic signing.